# Changing horizontal distance of columns in "songs" package

Tags: columns, songs

I want to flush a certain distance the columns to the left, not only alter the separation between them. I'm having problems as long verses "intrude" in the second column, and if I change the separation between columns, the long verses in the second column are chopped by the right side of the document. I need not only to increase the separation between them, but to move both to the left but I can't find anything about this in the documentation, only about column separation. Maybe increasing the column width can help, but it doesn't say anything about this neither in the documentation. In the screenshot you can see my code for that song and that all those side and top-bottom margins are not being used for wider and longer columns, which is what I need. In the preamble I added `\columnsep=2cm` so those 2 columns don't overlap, but if I increase the value to more than 2cm, the lyrics in the second column are chopped, so that's why I want to flush both columns to the left and then increase the column separation. [image: in the screenshot you can see that all those side and top-bottom margins are not being used for wider and longer columns, which is what I need]

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

Solved thanks to @cabohah !

Comment: I don't know `songs` and unfortunately you've not added a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) to make your problem reproducible and allow us to test our ideas. It also seems, that you have several problems. And usually it is not good to mix them into one question. But if you just want to change the document margins, have a look at [package `geometry`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry).

Comment: thanks @cabohah , I used geometry to make the margins 2cm and that solved the problem! The songs package has a page-builder integrated so that's why I was looking for a solution within the package, as I thought it would break the whole structure of the songbook, but works great :)

Comment: Note: A screenshot of code is not really useful, because we cannot copy&paste it to try it out and modify it. Please, always add code as code block. And please don't show only code snippets but always a MWE (see my link above).